# System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table x for for entity type x

Tags: c#, .net-5

I tried to migrate table using package console manager but error like this.

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot use table 'Quote' for entity type 'Sample' since it is being used for entity type 'Author' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'Sample' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity typed mapped to 'Quote'.'

these are my model class **Author.cs**

```
using Sieve.Attributes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Entities.Models
{
    public class Author : BaseEntity
    {
        [Sieve(CanFilter = true, CanSort = true)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Sieve(CanFilter = true, CanSort = true)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Sample> Quote { get; set; } //relasi table
    }
}
```

**Sample.cs** model:

```
using Sieve.Attributes;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Entities.Models
{
    [Table("Quote")]
    public class Sample : BaseEntity
    {
        [Column("Quote")]
        [Sieve(CanFilter = true, CanSort = true)]
        public string Quote { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(Author))]
        public Guid? AuthorId { get; set; }
        public Author Author { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here my **RepositoryContext.cs**:

```
using Entities.Configuration;
using Entities.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Entities
{
    public class RepositoryContext : DbContext
    {
        public RepositoryContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(RepositoryContext).Assembly);
        }

        public DbSet<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Author> Author { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, i was trying to migrate new table using package manager console. they has same error @marsze

Comment: Did you probably use table name "Quote" for a different entity type in a previous version?

Comment: hmm i think yes, how to change or checked that?

Comment: I assume, use a different name, or a temporary name and then a 2nd migration. Also, I recommend to use keep the table names the same as the entity names whenever possible, to prevent confusion.

Comment: Sorry, can you specify where's in my code need to change. There's table sample already on database, what i need to add is table author.

Comment: Ah now i get it what you mean about keep using same table names